# Error when building onto real device?

Tags: ios, xcode

My code builds fine when building to simulator. However, after connecting my iPad and building to it, I received the following error

> The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired
>   certificate/private key pair in your keychains

I am wondering if there is anything wrong in my configuration?

Comment: have you joined the _iOS Developer Program_ yet? do you have live enrollment? have you created the _Provision profile_ well for the test device UDIDs?

Comment: Please search before you add a question - this topic has already been covered in quite extensive detail.

Answer (score 0):

in your Target, go to build settings then search 'Code Signing Identity'.  Under Debug it's trying to automatically select a provisioning profile.

Have you signed up for the developer program?  You need to look into the provisioning portal and get a certificate for yourself

Answer (score 0):

First check if the valid private key is installed in your machine.
then you need to configure the valid Certificate in the CodeSigning under Build Settings.